# H2 embedded mode becomes slower than server mode

Tags: database, h2, embedded-database

While attempting to optimize a prototype application, H2 was identified as a bottleneck. I initially used H2 in server mode and inserts (and other DB operations) start out fast but rapidly become slower as the number of rows (and specifically, the DB file size) increase. Oddly enough, H2 in server mode starts out slower but doesn't suffer from the same performance degradation.

Also the embedded DB file size increases rapidly compared to the server mode DB file. I tried all manner of DB settings and they didn't make much difference.

To illustrate the issue, I've created an inclusive Spring Boot application and hosted it on github at https://github.com/balamuru/h2demo . I created a simple table with a MEDIUMBLOB field populated by the contents of a bitvector (to speed up the process of bulking up the DB)

```
admin.employee (
  id      BIGINT       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  address TEXT,
  data MEDIUMBLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

- Server mode db config

  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;CACHE_SIZE=1000000;`
- Embedded mode db config

  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./h2db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;CACHE_SIZE=1000000`
- Here are the results that illustrate my concern. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

`-------embedded mode (msecs)-------
Run time : 27464
Run time : 7281
Run time : 6363
Run time : 6326
Run time : 5522
Run time : 6070
Run time : 5262
Run time : 6502
Run time : 6016
Run time : 7196
Run time : 15735 ==> spike in run time
Run time : 39973 ==> embedded mode slower than server mode from this run onwards
Run time : 44079
Run time : 46769
Run time : 50443
Run time : 53640
Run time : 59635
Run time : 61937
Run time : 64344
Run time : 71259
-------server mode (msecs)-------
Run time : 20872
Run time : 17319
Run time : 18081
Run time : 18205
Run time : 18596
Run time : 18089
Run time : 18453
Run time : 18386
Run time : 18330
Run time : 17259
Run time : 18826
Run time : 19717
Run time : 19122
Run time : 18152
Run time : 18016
Run time : 18818
Run time : 19414
Run time : 19207
Run time : 19022
Run time : 19446`

Comment: Does the server mode have more free memory ?

Comment: Not from a config point, .. though it obviously uses a separate JVM for the DB. Just for grins, I bumped up Xmx to 1GB for the embedded mode and compared mem. usage to the test case JVM. For run #16, embedded mode had 382 MB Free & used 626 MB vs 187/234 for server mode (which was still faster) despite less allocated heap space

Comment: So the difference seems to come from the fact that one approach involves sending the data over the network (even if it is localhost) and therefore needs to be converted.

Comment: .. that 's my source of my confusion. The server (network) mode performance is constant and is eventually faster as the embedded mode performance degrades.

Comment: Your test is hard to analyze for me. Could you append `;trace_level_file=3` to the database URL in order to get the JDBC method calls? And then reduce the number of iterations, if possible to 5, so that the log file doesn't grow too big. Then we should check what the test is doing. Specially, if it opens and closes the database a lot in the embedded case. This is what is slow.

Comment: See traces (includes traces when the test case is fast and slow) at https://www.dropbox.com/s/oei44y9gbgk4i85/traces.tar.gz?dl=0 . The SQL times don't vary that much in the trace analysis, but the test case times do (15 seconds vs 86 seconds, for example). I used Xmx=2G for this test case.  Thanks